# Where am I going wrong with foreach when i try to get my script to run against each individual string in my results?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, script, shell-script

I have a Users.log file that lists the following information pertaining to Usernames, group memberships and assigned server paths extracted from AD:

```
RandomUser01,RandomGroup01_654321_098765,\\server\data\designs\RandomArea01_654321_098765\data_store
RandomUser02,RandomGroup02_654321_098765,\\server\data\designs\RandomArea02_654321_098765\data_store
RandomUser03,RandomGroup03_654321_098765,\\server\data\designs\RandomArea03_654321_098765\data_store
RandomUser04,RandomGroup04_654321_098765,\\server\data\designs\RandomArea04_654321_098765\data_store
MyUsername,MyGroup01_654321_098765,\\server\data\designs\MyArea01_654321_098765\data_store
MyUsername,MyGroup02_654321_098765,\\server\data\designs\Myrea02_654321_098765\data_store
```

The script is intended to first check if any shortcut containing the word "data" already exists, then isolate the strings in the users.log file that contain my username (`Select-String $env:username`), filter down the results to just the UNC server path (`$ServerPath = $Object -replace ”[^,]*,”,””`), and use it to create a unique desktop shortcut to the server. It's also set to use the group name as the shortcut name (`$ShortcutName = $ProjectName.Substring(0, $ProjectName.IndexOf('_'))`)

Script:

```
function Set-ShortCut {
    Param ( 
        [string]$SourceLnk, 
        [string]$DestinationPath 
    )
        
        $WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
        $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($SourceLnk)
        $Shortcut.TargetPath = $DestinationPath
        $Shortcut.Save()

}

$WantFile = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\data*.lnk"
$FileExists = Test-Path $WantFile
$FindUser = Get-Content \\Server\data\logs\Users.log | Select-String $env:username



If ($FileExists -eq $False)


{

Write-Host "Conditions have been satisfied. Running script to create data_store shortcut"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5


foreach ($Object in $FindUser) 
{
$ProjectName = $finduser -split ",", 3 | Select-Object -Index 1 
$ShortcutName = $ProjectName.Substring(0, $ProjectName.IndexOf('_'))
$ServerPath = $Object -replace ”[^,]*,”,””
$SourcePath = "$ServerPath"
$ProjectName
$ShortcutName
$ServerPath
$SourcePath
Set-ShortCut -SourceLnk "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\$ShortcutName data_store.lnk" -DestinationPath $SourcePath
}




}

Else {

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
Write-Host "The Script will now EXIT..."
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
Exit
}
```

I want the script to run once *for each string* found in the results of `$FindUser`. Which is why I have used `foreach ($Object in $FindUser)`. But I can't get the script to do this.

In this users.log file example, when i run `$FindUser` it yields two results:

```
MyUsername,MyGroup01_654321_098765,\\server\data\designs\MyArea01_654321_098765\data_store
MyUsername,MyGroup02_654321_098765,\\server\data\designs\Myrea02_654321_098765\data_store
```

However, I think I've made a mistake in my use of `foreach`. I've also tried `ForEach-Object` and no luck. Does anyone have any suggestions? I need the script to run against each string within `$FindUsers` individually. At the moment it just runs once on all the results within `$FindUsers` collectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to this line of code:

```ps
$ProjectName = $finduser -split ",", 3 | Select-Object -Index 1
```

During each iteration, you are using `$FindUser` instead  of `$Object`. You should change it to:

```
$ProjectName = $Object -split ",", 3 | Select-Object -Index 1
```